# How to execute GIT commands from Chef recipe on Windows when repository is AWS CodeCommit?

Tags: windows, git, powershell, chef-recipe, aws-codecommit

My repository is on AWS CodeCommit. I have run the command to configure aws cli:

```
aws configure --profile test
```

I have assigned policy '*AWSCodeCommitPowerUser*' to my IAM user.
I have pointed my GIT credential manager to use my AWS profile:

```
git config --global credential.helper '!aws --profile test codecommit credential-helper $@'
git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
```

I have verified that `.aws` directory and `.gitconfig` file are properly created for my user inside C:\Users\[my_user]\

I have verified that I am able to perform `git pull` command from my powershell console in the required git controlled directories.

However, when i run the same command from within a Chef recipe, it fails to update the git directories. I keep getting the git timeout error and notice a Git Credential Manager task running in task manager; after which my recipe fails. My chef-client is on version: **12.14.89**

How do I get it to work?

Comment: What user is running the chef recipe? If it is a different user or running via a service started as a different user, you will need to configure both aws and git for that user too

Comment: I've ensured all that, running my chef-client via the windows_task resource started with the domain user i have configured stuff for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a summary of failed efforts:

```
powershell_script 'git-sync' do
    cwd "#{ENV['HOME']}']}"
    code <<-EOH
        git pull
    EOH
end
```

Doesn't work because the resource runs powershell with a -NoProfile tag and user's settings are not loaded

```
ruby_block 'git-sync' do
    block do
        script <<-EOH
            git pull
        EOH
    end
    result = powershell_out(script)
    if (!result.stdout.to_s.empty?)
        Chef::Log.info("GIT command output::\n#{result.stdout.to_s}")
    end
end
```

Same problem, doesn't work.
yser

```
git "#{node.run_state['git_directory']}" do
    repository "#{node.run_state['git_repo']}"
    revision "#{node.run_state['git_branch']}"
    action :sync
    user "#{ENV['USER']}"
end
```

The one above doesn't work because one has to specify `user` attribute and fails because of an absurd error complaining about some nil directory. Upon inspection, I realized that the resource would only probably work with linux the underlying ruby file uses Etc.getpwnam(..)

Now, the solution:

recipe ***git_sync.rb***:

```
ruby_block 'git-sync' do
    block do
    psFile = "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/cookbooks/#{cookbook_name}/files/git_align.ps1"
    node.run_state['git_directories'].each { |location| 
        scriptOutput = `powershell.exe -NoLogo -NonInteractive -File #{psFile} #{location} #{node.run_state['git_branch']}`
        Chef::Log.info("Git Sync Output::\n#{scriptOutput}")
    }
    end
end
```

powershell script ***git_align.ps1***:

```
Param(
    [string]$location,
    [string]$branch_name
)
Try{
    $output = ""
    $loc = Resolve-Path -path $location
    if ($loc -eq $null) {throw "$location not found"}
    Set-Location $loc
    $output+= "At location $loc`n"

    $curr_branch = git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
    if ($curr_branch -ne $branch_name){
    $output+= git checkout $branch_name
    $output+= "`n"
    }
    if ($? -eq $false) {throw "GIT checkout failed"}

    $output+= git reset --hard origin/$branch_name
    $output+= "`n"
    if ($? -eq $false) {throw "GIT reset failed"}

    $output+= git pull
    $output+= "`n"
    if ($? -eq $false) {throw "GIT pull failed"}

    Write-Output $output
}
Catch{
    $exc = $_.Exception | format-list -force
    Write-Output $exc
    Throw $exc
}
```

Hope it helps! Chef sometimes seems like an ocean, and nobody should have to swim alone!